# How would I make Google web map android native map?

Tags: android, google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova

I was developing an Android app under the jQuery mobile framework using phoneGap technology. The app included Google maps.

The problem is, it is too slow .... really slow.. I tested it on several android devices and found the same issue everywhere.

I'd like for maps to run like they do on the native Android Google Maps (default). Is this a common issue using the mentioned framework, or perhaps something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I edited this quite a bit for clarity, but it would be useful if you could include some more info. If you need more editing help, feel free to ping me in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your modification. But don't getting any new answers. Can I post new same question?

Comment: It's better to just add more info to this question, please don't ask a duplicate.

Comment: Can you help me regarding the question?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is fire an Intent to make the native Maps application take care of your mapping needs, if that works for you.

For example, if you want to show the user a map of a given address, you can fire a android.action.VIEW Intent, with a URI like:

geo:0,0?q=1234+foo+bar+qux+avenue

More info on available system intents:
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. But I want a javascript solution for the native files. I think you understand

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WebIntent